# Change (sub)section numbering in article document class so that it becomes 1.1 instead of 1, etc

Tags: sectioning, chapters, article

With the help of

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
{\thechapter}% <search>
{\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname\else\ifnum\value{chapter}<10
    0\fi\fi\thechapter}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

I was able to change the chapter numbering in `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}` from `Chapter 1`, `Chapter 2`, `Chapter 3`, etc. to `Chapter 01`, `Chapter 02`, `Chapter 03`, etc.

But when writing sections within the chapters, their numbering begins with `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.

I would like my chapters to look like `Chapter 01`, `Chapter 02`, `Chapter 03`, etc., my sections (of `Chapter 01`) to look like `1.1`, `1.2`, `1.3`, etc. and my subsections (of `Chapter 01`) to look like `1.1.1`, `1.1.2`, `1.2.1`, `1.2.2`, `1.2.3`, etc.

How can I do that within a `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}` document?

---

**Edit:** My full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=false,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\newlength{\hangwidth}
\newcommand{\myhang}[1]{\settowidth{\hangwidth}{#1}\hangpara{\hangwidth}{1}#1}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
{\thechapter}% <search>
{\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname\else\ifnum\value{chapter}<10
    0\fi\fi\thechapter}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{2cm}
        \centering
        {\scshape\LARGE Title page\par}
    \end{titlepage}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \chapter{One}
    \section{First section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why just change heading rather than the numbering ? if the second chapter has heading **02** don't you want references to it to be to 02 rather than 2 ?  if so you can just change `\thechapter` (and `\thesection` etc) to prefix a 0.

Comment: the default numbering of sections in report class is 1.1, 1.2,.. in chapter 1, so if you are getting 1,2,.. then you have changed that somewhere in code not shown.

Comment: as always the question would be clearer if it included a test document.

Comment: You were right. I have found a solution. (See edit above.)

Comment: @Nemgathos Please don't put the answer in your question. Add an answer or delete your question, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Just remove `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` and it works. I did not see it at first glance and it has not been provided with the original question.